# How to take input from the user only once with the help of a function and then use it in all of the other functions?

Tags: solidity, remix

Here I take input from the user in every function to perform the calculation but what if I wanted to take the two input numbers from the user only once and then perform all the rest of functions with those 2 numbers only.
Like take the input numbers and then only click the specific button for the function that comes after deploying the contract in remix.
For addition, subtraction etc.

Code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT;
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 < 0.9.0;

contract SimpleCalculator{
function addTwoNumbers(uint256 number1,uint256 number2) public view returns(uint256){
    uint256 addition = number1 + number2;
    return addition;
}
function subtractTwoNumbers(int number1,int256 number2) public view returns(int256){
    int256 subtraction = number1 - number2;
    return subtraction;
}
function divideTwoNumbers(uint256 number1,uint number2) public view returns(uint256){
    uint256 division = number1/number2;
    return division;
}
function multiplyTwoNumbers(uint256 number1, uint256 number2) public view returns(uint256){
    uint256 multiplication = number1*number2;
    return multiplication;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you need, but I wrote this quick example of how to have a single function that orchestrates all the operations and returns one result with all the operations.

Take a look at the `doAllOperations` function. Basically I created an `Operations` struct to save all the results of all these operations and return this struct:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT;
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 < 0.9.0;

struct Operations {
    uint256 sum;
    uint256 substraction;
    uint256 division;
    uint256 multiplication;
}

contract SimpleCalculator {

    function doAllOperations(uint256 number1,uint256 number2) public pure returns(Operations memory) {

        Operations memory operationsResult = Operations({
            sum: addTwoNumbers(number1, number2),
            substraction: subtractTwoNumbers(number1, number2),
            division: divideTwoNumbers(number1, number2),
            multiplication: multiplyTwoNumbers(number1, number2)
        });

        return operationsResult;

    }

    function addTwoNumbers(uint256 number1, uint256 number2) public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint256 addition = number1 + number2;
        return addition;
    }

    function subtractTwoNumbers(uint256 number1, uint256 number2) public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint256 subtraction = number1 - number2;
        return subtraction;
    }

    function divideTwoNumbers(uint256 number1, uint number2) public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint256 division = number1/number2;
        return division;
    }

    function multiplyTwoNumbers(uint256 number1, uint256 number2) public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint256 multiplication = number1*number2;
        return multiplication;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I got you covered:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT;
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 < 0.9.0;

contract SimpleCalculator{

    uint number1;
    uint number2;

    function setImputNumbers(uint firstNumber, uint secondNumber) public {
        number1 = firstNumber;
        number2 = secondNumber;
    }

    function addTwoNumbers() public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 addition = number1 + number2;
        return addition;
    }

    function subtractTwoNumbers() public view returns(int256){
        int256 subtraction = int(number1) - int(number2);
        return subtraction;
    }

    function divideTwoNumbers() public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 division = number1/number2;
        return division;
    }

    function multiplyTwoNumbers() public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 multiplication = number1*number2 ;
        return multiplication;
    }

}
```

It's a simple code that does exactly what you requested. So now you can play/experiment with it. I haven't optimized or covered possible mathematical edge cases that can go wrong (division by zero). But its perfectly suitable otherwise for learning solidity.